# Application failed codesign verification, iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval, flash-cs5.5

I have made an app for the iPhone using flash CS 5.5, tested it on a device (it works fine on there) and I'm member of the development programme. I'm attempting to upload the app to the store after filling in all the information on iTunes connect. However, when I attempt to upload the ipa file through the Application Loader (Version 2.5.2) I keep encountering the same error:

> 'Application failed code sign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.'

I've tried creating the certificates again but still getting the same error.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: R u sure that the selected distribution profile is correct and is given at the right place?

Answer (score 3):

It means that you are not using *iPhone Distribution Certificate*, which is required to upload apps on the app store. I'm guessing you are using a developer certificate.

Here is link how to create distribution certificate for app store submission: [Steps to create a distribtution certificate.](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-create-distribution-build-with.html)

Next time do a search you'll get plenty questions related to this topic. For example:
[Application failed codesign verification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888943/application-failed-codesign-verification)

Answer (score 1):

Try again with your release certificates, and make sure that whatever you are quoting there for making the certificate should be same as you app's plist file.

Refer to this links: [Building Your App for Distribution](http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/build.html)